# Finding exact values associated with given word using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

am trying to find values associated with a particular word using regex but not getting expected results.
I wrote a pattern that is working fine for standard input only and I want to so the same for all sorts of inputs.

What I have now:

```
string = r'''results on 12/28/2012: WBC=8.110*3, RBC=3.3010*6, Hgb=11.3gm/dL'''
```

Pattern which I wrote:

```
re.findall(r'{}=(.*)'.format(detected_word), search_query)[0].split(',')[0]
```

detected_word is variable where am detecting left side part of equals sign like (WBC, RBC,...) using another technique.

In this above case, it's working fine, but if I change the sentence pattern like below am unable to find a generic pattern.

```
string = r'''results on 12/28/2012: WBC=8.110*3, RBC=3.3010*6 and Hgb=11.3gm/dL'''
string = r'''results for WBC, RBC and Hgb are 8.110*3, 3.3010*6 and 11.3gm/dL'''
```

no matter of string format I can able to detect WBC, RBC, and Hgb these words but detecting the value for an associated word is worrying me

Could anyone please help me with this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are certain bout the order of the values are WBC, RBC, and Hgb on all records, you can use this regex to capture the values `\d+\.\d+(\*\d|gm\/dL)`. This sounds like an XY problem. Try to describe what you want to do than how you want to do it. There may be better solutions. :)

Comment: The last example is hard to get with a regex. If you want, it can be written and it will match in certain contexts, but you should probably look for an NLP based solution, like SpaCy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea: use two separate patterns for the strings you provided as sample input, the first one will extract values coming after *expected word=* and the other will extract them from clauses of *expected word1* + optional *expected word2* + optional *expected word3* + "to be" verb + *value1*, optional *value2* and optional *value3*.

**Pattern 1**:

```
\b(WBC|RBC|Hgb)=(\S*)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/prOUR5/1).

- `\b(WBC|RBC|Hgb)` - a whole word `WBC`, `RBC` or `Hgb`
- `=` - a `=` char
- `(\S*)\b` - Group 2: 0 or more non-whitespaces, that stops at last word boundary position

**Pattern 2**:

```
\b(WBC|RBC|Hgb)(?:(?:\s+and)?(?:\s*,)?\s+(WBC|RBC|Hgb))?(?:(?:\s+and)?(?:\s*,)?\s*(WBC|RBC|Hgb))?\s+(?:is|(?:a|we)re|was|will\s+be)(?:\s*,)?\s*(\d\S*)\b(?:(?:\s+and)?(?:\s*,)?\s*(\d\S*)\b)?(?:(?:\s+and)?(?:\s*,)?\s*(\d\S*)\b)?
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/prOUR5/3).

- `\b(WBC|RBC|Hgb)` - Group 1 capturing the searched word
- `(?:(?:\s+and)?(?:\s*,)?\s*(WBC|RBC|Hgb))?` - an optional pattern:

  - `(?:\s+and)?` - an optional sequence of 1+ whitespaces and then `and`
  - `(?:\s*,)?` -  an optional sequence of 0+ whitespaces and then a comma
  - `\s*(WBC|RBC|Hgb)` - 0+ whitespaces and Group 2 capturing the searched word
- `(?:(?:\s+and)?(?:\s*,)?\s*(WBC|RBC|Hgb))?` - same as above, captures the 3rd optional searched word into Group 3
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?:is|(?:a|we)re|was|will\s+be)` - a VERB, you may add more if you expect them to be at this position, or plainly try a `\S+` or `\w+` pattern instead
- `(?:\s*,)?\s*` - an optional 0+ whitespaces and a comma sequence, then 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d\S*)\b` - Group 4 (pair it with Group 1 value): a digit and then 0+ non-whitespace chars limited by a word boundary
- `(?:(?:\s+and)?(?:\s*,)?\s*(\d\S*)\b)?` - an optional group matching

  - `(?:\s+and)?` - an optional sequence of 1+ whitespaces and `and`
  - `(?:\s*,)?\s*` - an optional 0+ whitespaces and a comma, then 0+ whitespaces
  - `(\d\S*)\b` - Group 5 (pair it with Group 2 value): a digit and then 0+ non-whitespace chars limited by a word boundary
- `(?:(?:\s+and)?(?:\s*,)?\s*(\d\S*)\b)?` - same as above, with a capture group 6 that must be paired with Group 3.